# Mozart's Requiem

Tags: mozart

We all know that he only completed the sections of I. Requiem, II. Dies irae, and III. Tuba mirum. While the rest was fragments and was completed by his pupil.

Why did Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart failed to finish his Requiem in D Minor K. 626?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

He was not agile enough. Salieri gave him a deadline of 2 weeks but he failed. Mozart was not agile enough. Mozart was like a snail.

Comment: Dying does have a tendency to slow one down.

Answer (score 3):

He died. Unexpectedly. In those days there were no antibiotics and not much understanding of illness.

Comment: mercury poisoning perhaps?

Comment: Somewhere I read that Mozart died of some type of kidney infection. This was a tentative clinical diagnosis (AKA guess) based on reading contemporary (with Mozart, not us) sources.